# How to find total angular velocity of an object rotating about 2 axes, then find angular acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

> A disc of radius *r*, attached with a horizontal axle is rolling without sliding on a circular track of radius *R*. The center of the disc moves with a constant speed *v*. Find the angular acceleration of the disc.

[image: Problem diagram]

I am not able to understand how the angular acceleration is simply the product of the angular velocities. Please guide me on this problem.

Comment: Calculate the disk’s angular velocity vector as a function of time, and take its time derivative. That’s the *definition* of angular acceleration.

Comment: Please note that homework-like questions are generally off-topic. Unless you ask a specific *conceptual* question rather than “How do I do this?”, such questions are likely to get closed.

Comment: @G.Smith Isn't the angular velocity vector independent of time?

Comment: $\boldsymbol {\vec \omega_0}$ is constant. However, the direction of $\boldsymbol {\vec \omega}$ keeps changing (although its magnitude remains the same). So the total angular velocity $\boldsymbol{\vec\Omega} = \boldsymbol{\vec \omega_0}+\boldsymbol {\vec \omega}$ will also change